# Link to new activity usin AsyncTask onPostExecute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have problem on link the main page to other page. I already search and run all the q&a that already been asked here, but has error. 
Can someone help me.. it is very useful.. tq

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
AlertDialog alertDialog;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information...");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate (Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

this is the part...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute (String result)
{

    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

     //Want to go new activity page`enter code here`

}
}
```

already try this but cannot work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyAsyncTaskActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: could you provide your code in onCreate()

Comment: is there any exceptions? please include logcat

Comment: You should not be able to call `getApplicationContext()` inside an `AsyncTask`, unless it is an inner class of an `Activity`. Follow `Sjd`'s answer and use your passed `Context` object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this structure

```
public class MyAsyncTaskActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
            ....
            new BackgroundTask().execute();
            ....
        }

        private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                // ….

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyAsyncTaskActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //optional
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is the simplest way, but using a non-static inner `AsyncTask` class can leave your app vulnerable to memory leaks

Comment: @PPartisan Could you give me some suggestion to make this code better. thank you

Comment: You could make the class `static` (or a separate class file), pass the `Activity` as an argument, and store it inside a `WeakReference<>` object. in your constructor Or, you could use an interface to call a method in `postExecute()` that starts a new `Activity` inside the `Activity` class itself. [Link](http://partisanapps.com/2015/08/really-useful-notes-saving-and-loading-with-a-local-database-i/)

Comment: For this question i will still keep this simplest answer but I will read about your document. I think it will be really new and helpful for me.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NextActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //optional
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
```